# Change NaN to Error in JavaScript calculator

Tags: javascript, jquery, nan

I have a JavaScript calculator which has numerous functions defined as follows (using `ln` as an example):

```
function ln(form) {
  form.display.value = Math.log(form.display.value);
}
```

If the user inputs a negative number and clicks the button to activate this function, it returns `NaN` since `ln` is undefined for negative values. I would like for it to return `Error` however. I have tried this, but it causes the script to stop working:

```
var displayValue = form.display.value;
if (isNaN(displayValue)) displayValue = 'Error';
```

Here is the HTML markup of the display if required:

```
<INPUT NAME="display" ID="disp" VALUE="0" SIZE="28" MAXLENGTH="25"/>
```

How might I get this to return the desired output?

Comment: Are you changing the `form.display.value` or `displayValue`'s value?

Comment: @choz The `form.display.value`. Basically I want the input display of the calculator to read `Error` instead of `NaN`.

Comment: Then why would you do `displayValue = 'Error'` instead of `form.display.value = 'Error'`?

Comment: @choz Using `form.display.value` causes the script to stop working altogether. I'm looking for an alternative.

Comment: Where do you put that `form.display.value = 'Error'` at? Please post it here. I bet the handler which causes your script to stop working since it recursively keeps parsing `Math.log('Error')` and gives the result as a `NaN` and so on..

Comment: var displayValue = form.display.value;
if (isNaN(displayValue)) form.display.value = 'Error'; --> Tried this.

Comment: I mean post it on your question, and **not** just those lines. **All** of it with the handlers.

Comment: Yes, show us your code in context and we might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function ln(form) {
    if(isNan(Math.log(form.display.value))){
       form.display.value = 'Error';
    } else {
      form.display.value = Math.log(form.display.value);
    } 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The value returned from `form.display.value` is a String. This means that [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) will always return `true` if the value cannot be parsed into a `Number`. You need to change this value to a `Number` first:

```
function ln(form) {
  var displayValue = parseFloat(form.display.value);

  if(isNaN(displayValue)){
    form.display.setAttribute('value', 'Error');
  } else {
    form.display.setAttribute('value', Math.log(displayValue));
  } 
}
```

Comment: Again, not sure why this is the case, but the `ln` button no longer functions when I try this.

Comment: There was a typo. I wrote `isNan` instead of `isNaN`.

Comment: `isNaN('5') === false`

Comment: Still returns `NaN` - Thanks for trying though!

Comment: That was a horrible error @RyanO'Hara . I did link to the documentation so it may have buffered the effect.